# Is it safe to reuse the same random session number r in the Guillou-Quisquarter protocol?

Tags: rsa

I basically use the method below, one difference is that after receiving the first proof the verifier asks the prover to create a proof for another challenge d and this several times without having the prover generate a new random value r.
Is this safe? I was not able to find indications in the literature about it and r is never defined as a nonce but I am afraid this could leak the provers secret key A.

> Guillou and Quisquater ([link][1]) present a zero-knowledge proof of
>   an RSA signature. Basically, the scheme is as follows:
>
> Public knowledge: RSA modulus $n$, public RSA exponent $v$, preimage
>   $X$.
>
> Secret knowledge for prover: $A$, such that $A^v = X \mod n$.
>
> $$ \begin{matrix} \mathcal{P} & & \mathcal{V} \\ r \xleftarrow{\$}
>  \mathbb{Z}_n^* \phantom{\mod n} & & \\ T \leftarrow r^v \mod n & & \\ 
>  & \xrightarrow{\quad{}T\quad{}} & \\  & & d \xleftarrow{\$}
>  \{0,1,\ldots,v-1\} \\  & \xleftarrow{d} & \\  t \leftarrow A^dr \mod n
>  & & \\  & \xrightarrow{\quad{}t\quad} & \\  & & t^v \stackrel{?}{=}
>  X^{d}T \mod n \end{matrix} $$
>
> In this diagram, $\leftarrow$ denotes assignment of a value to a
>   variable and $\xleftarrow{\$}$ denotes uniformly random selection from
>   a finite set.
>
> [1]: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=88372

Comment: The computation seems a bit tricky, but yes, knowing the prover answers to two different $d$ queries for the same $r$ allows extraction of $A$. The details are in the paper you cited and which is available as a [PDF here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/0-387-34799-2_16.pdf) (sections 2 and 3) and a bit too tricky for me to just whip out an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this safe?

No, it is not.  Here is how it would be easy to recover $A$:

- The prover generates $r$ and publishes $T$, and the verifier selects an arbitrary challenge $d$.  The prover responds with $T = A^d \cdot r$
- The prover generates the same $r$ and publishes the same $T$.  The verifier selects the next $d' = d+1$ as his challenge, and the prover responds with $T' = A^{d'} \cdot r$

The verifier can then compute $T' \cdot T^{-1} = (A^{d+1} \cdot r) / (A^d \cdot r) = A$, thus recovering the secret.

> I was not able to find indications in the literature about it and r is never defined as a nonce but I am afraid this could leak the provers secret key A.

Actually, it's not a nonce; calling something a nonce implies that the only requirement it has is that values never repeat,  In this case, you can devise ways to exploit related $r$'s as well; for example, if it's a simple incrementing pattern, that is, $r' = r+1$, then the attacker just selects $d = d' = 1$.  There might be nonrandom update patterns that are safe, but why risk it?

In general, using nonrandom challenges (either repeating or related) within a zero knowledge protocol does leak the secret.